# Access method via instance and static

Tags: c#

Is it possible to create a class that has a method definition where the method can be accessed statically, and also be accessed via an instance of the class, without having to have two separate names for the method or a separate set of arguments to distinguish the methods as two different methods.

i.e.

```
public class MyClass
{
    public static int GetMyInt()
    {
        return 1;
    }
}

...

MyClass classInst = new MyClass();

int i = MyClass.GetMyInt();
int x = classInst.GetMyInt();
```

Is this possible in C#? If so, how so?

Comment: You could use a static method with an optional MyClass parameter.

Comment: Don't think so... However following is the best I can think of:

void Main()
{
 var instance = new I();
 
 instance.J(0).Dump("Instance");
 
 I.J().Dump("Static");
}

// Define other methods and classes here

public class I
{
 public static int J()
 {
  return 1;
 }
 
 public int J(params int[] k)
 {
  return 1;
 }
}

Answer (score 2):

No. A method is `static` or is not.

I don't a valid use case you want to allow calling a `static` method against an instance of a class.

Comment: currently moving a lot of code that used instances of a class, where the class and all of its methods should have been static and am looking to refactor the class to be static without killing backwards compatibility and having to refactor more or less every other class in a 300,000 SLOC application.

Comment: @bizzehdee I understand your case, but it's a breaking change: if you want to keep backwards compatibility, your new static method must have a new (different) name.

Answer (score 2):

A static (or class) method is by definition different from an instance method.
An instance method is only accessible when you create an instance of that class;
A static method is always accessible, since it doesn't require class instanciation (provided it is public), at least always accessible within the class itself. You should know, however, that if you have a static variable, any changes made to that variable will affect the class, and have an impact everywhere that variable is used on the application.
eg.

`...
static int lastId;
public static int getLastId(){
    return lastId++;
}`

This is a way you may control an autonumber on a class, since whenever you call getLastId, lastId will be incremented and that is valid for all the application.

**edit**
the sample code illustrates what happens with a static variable. That said, you should know that overloading is supported on c#. What you cannot have is a pair of methods with the same name tag and the same set and type of parameters.
for eg., this builds ok.

        `public static int getValue()
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public int getValue(int x)
        {
            return x * 1;
        }`

but this will throw an error:

        `public static int getValue(int z)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public int getValue(int x)
        {
            return x * 1;
        }`

that is true independently of wether there is a static method or not. This will also generate a compile time error:

        `public int getValue(int z)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public int getValue(int x)
        {
            return x * 1;
        }`

even this will give you an error:

        `public string getValue(int z)
        {
            return 1;
        }
        public int getValue(int x)
        {
            return x * 1;
        }`

so, yes, you may have a static method with the same name tag of an instance method, but you may not have the same set and type of parameters.
If you want both static an instance methods to have the same behaviour, then why do you need the intance method really? The static method will do the trick (considering you know the consequences of having a static method and its implications).

Comment: i am aware of the differences between an instance method and a static method. although i dont understand why this answer contains an example of auto numbers when the question had absolutely nothing to do with it.

Comment: If you haven't found a solution for this issue, you may also try creating your methods with the same name tag, but add a "dummy" parameter with a default value to one of them: `..., bool dummy = true) {...`

Answer (score 2):

I dont think you can have the cake and eat the cake too.

Static (methods which are called through class) and non-static (methods which are called through instance of class ) are two opposite sides of a coin.

So either it is static or non-static but not both

Answer (score 0):

Nope. But you can wrap it. But will have to give it a new signature.

```
    public int getMyInt()
    {
       return  GetMyInt();
    }
```

Comment: without a different name